# How to get key generated by Hibernate when I map a collection with @collectionId?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on Quiz management. All mapping is done by Hibernate annotation  for question to options.   Question is an entity whereas all options are embedded object so I mapped option as follows :

QuestionMasterDTO's mapping for `TabkidsMCQOptionMasterDTO` :

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetClass=TabkidsMCQOptionMasterDTO.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @CollectionTable(name="TABKIDS_MCQ_OPTION_MASTER",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TMOM_QUESTION_ID")})
    @GenericGenerator(name="hilo-gen",strategy="hilo")
    @CollectionId(columns={@Column(name="TMOM_ID")},generator="hilo-gen", type=@Type(type="long"))
    public Collection<IOptionMaster> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }
```

Where TabkidsMCQOptionMasterDTO is :

```
   @Embeddable
    public class TabkidsMCQOptionMasterDTO  implements IOptionMaster {

        private String optionText;
        private boolean correct;


        @Column(name = "TMOM_OPTION_TEXT")
        public String getOptionText() {
            return optionText;
        }

        @Column(name = "TMOM_IS_CORRECT")
        public boolean isCorrect() {
            return correct;

        }
      //setters omitted
}
```

Now in above mapping you can see I am using a generator i.e. `hilo-gen` and assigning a unique id to every option available in collection and that column name is '`TMOM_ID`'.

This line  :

```
@GenericGenerator(name="hilo-gen",strategy="hilo")
@CollectionId(columns={@Column(name="TMOM_ID")},generator="hilo-gen", type=@Type(type="long"))
```

Now when I fetch a  question from database by using Hibernate criteria I  am getting all options associated with the question but not getting unique  option id i.e. `TMOM_ID`. How to get this id ??

Comment: If you want any additional information plz comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate  mainly uses two type of mapping `Entity Type` and `Value Type`.

Entity type means It will have its own existence in the world i.e. It must have a primary key.

Whereas Value type don't have its own existence this means value type always dependent  on Entity type.

As your problem I  can see Option does not have its won existence because it must always dependent of Question which is an entity .

So from my point of view if you want to access Option Id, Option  must also be an entity type this means You have to use @Entity on top of  `TabkidsMCQOptionMasterDTO` rather than making it as `@Embeddable`.

So here you have to use `@OneToMany`  in your question master and from Other side in `TabkidsMCQOptionMasterDTO`  you have to use `@ManyToOne` mapping.

I hope this will help to achieve what you want to get.